# how to model a many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the scenario,
Articles have many Comments
Users can write many Comments for many Articles

The comments table contains both

```
user_id
article_id
```

as foreign keys

My models are set up like so

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :articles, :through => :comments

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :users, :through => :comments

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :articles
```

My routes.rb has the following code

```
  map.resources :articles, :has_many => :comments  
  map.resources :users, :has_many => :comments
```

which produces the following routes

```
new_article_comment
edit_article_comment
new_user_comment
edit_user_comment
etc...
```

This is not what I want (atleast not what I think I want), since comments must always be related to users and article, how can I get a route like so

```
new_user_article_comment
edit_user_article_comment
```

Then I could just do

```
new_user_article_comment_path([@user, @article])
```

to create a new comment

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this using nested routes. This article has a good example of how to do that:

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

Note that the article is basically saying "don't do it":

> "Rule of thumb: resources should never
>   be nested more than 1 level deep. A
>   collection may need to be scoped by
>   its parent, but a specific member can
>   always be accessed directly by an id,
>   and shouldn’t need scoping (unless the
>   id is not unique, for some reason)."

**However**, the above quote doesn't really apply to your action, as well as other cases where the unique id is not (yet) available,  since you don't yet have a unique id for the comment, and the user and article ids are absolutely necessary. A comment on that same page offers this qualification:

> Thijs van der Vossen said...
>   "We’ve invented a second rule of thumb;
>   resources should only be nested for
>   actions that really need the parent id
>   (like ‘index’, ‘new’, and ‘create’). 
>   We started using this for an
>   application with a data model that’s
>   almost entirely hierarchical except
>   where it’s not and it seems to work
>   very nicely. Why keep the parent
>   resource in the url when the structure
>   is not strictly hierarchical?"

Comment: My comments table does have a unique identifier, its id column that rails creates automatically for every table.

Comment: That's right, but at the point when you're creating a new comment by calling new_user_article_comment_path([@user, @article]) you won't (yet) have a unique id.

Comment: I see, I dont understand how nesting will work in my situation.
nesting users > articles > comments doesnt work, because it means that I must have a user_id foreign key in the article table.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a circular database schema. Not really recommended.

The data model should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
```

And the basic routing:

```
map.resources :articles do |articles|
  articles.resources :comments
end
```

And then decide what else do you need to make it fit your requirements.